# CSS positioning of checkbox and radio buttons

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to create a simple css form based on a short article by Antonio Lupetti, but in his example, he does not show you how to position your radio or checkbox fields.

I would like my checkbox to the right instead of Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong with these two fields? I am completely unable to get a nice looking appearance.  Thank you.

```
.form_style input[type="checkbox"]{
float:left;
}
.form_style input[type="radio"]{
float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kFkSh/

Comment: _"I would like my checkbox to the right instead of "_. What's that mean?

Comment: The css you have listed here in your question does not show up at all in the fiddle you provided, not sure what you're asking.

Comment: `.form_style input` <- Bad selector, you are targeting all the input together... http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/kFkSh/1/

Comment: Also, your float has gone totally wrong

Comment: I guess that css forms can be quite complex and I really don't know if I am taking the wrong approach. At the bottom, I posted a jsfiddle that looks good (thanks to everyone's help) but the css seems overly complex. On the other hand, the html is extremely simple which is what I wanted. If anyone can recommend some css form template that I could look at, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the fiddle includes a small section that explains that both true/false radio options should be on the same line:

In order to fix that, change:

```
.form_style input{
float:left;
font-size:12px;
padding:4px 2px;
border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
width:200px;
margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
}
```

To this:

```
.form_style input{
font-size:12px;
padding:4px 2px;
border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
}
```

Comment: I carefully looked at everyone's answer which were helpful, but the one written by Culyx was the most helpful. Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/kFkSh/4/

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are targeting input which will capture your radio buttons and checkboxes 
Add an atrribute selector to that [type='text'] then move on from there

Comment: I wish I could share the 'accept' with you as well because that selector was also very helpful to me.